# ASP.NET/Ionic - REST API hosted in Azure receives Guid with partial Zeroes from Ionic when using SSL

Tags: asp.net, azure, ssl, ionic-framework

We have a backend hosted in Azure with a REST API running on it and our clients are made in Ionic both Android and Ios devices. The problem is that when we make calls from client to server, there are calls that can be solved with no problems, there is a correct request and response, but when the client calls the API with a request like this

```
GET http://myservice.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/cards?customerId=72110785-cccb-4a90-80a4-399881c1442f
```

We receive a 500 Internal Error (due to a Null Refference Exception) because of the backend controller that handles the request receives:

```
4332fcc1-f100-0000-0000-000000000000
```

So, the thing is that backend cannot understand the request made by the client. This problem appeared because of [the changes iOS needed with transport security](http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/). We were working without SSL in Android and everything was fine, it worked perectly, but when we applied SSL changes to iOS version we tried these changes in Android and it crashed the same way. Is it a matter of SSL certificate? We think it could be the problem but the other calls made to the API are working fine and only the call made with a Guid in the URI is the one that is giving us problems. We don't know what to do and we are forced to use SSL in clients.